# Localizing Search module strings

Tags: search, i18n-l10n

Has anyone been successful in localizing/translating strings pertaining to the Search module? At first, I wanted to translate the "search results" head string and on this page `admin/config/regional/translate/translate` looked up "search" in general - no such string was found... Or, is there a way to override strings through a custom module?